# Trouble transfering file from a server to another server

Tags: php

Hello guys i'm having trouble uploading a file from my server to my friends server using php. At first i was getting a 26 error now i am getting this error:

```
Error: Possible file upload attack: filename ''.Array ( ) 1
```

Below is my code

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init();
chmod("grademegood.us/uploadedfiles/hello.txt", 0755);

  $post =array(
  'file' => '@' . realpath('./uploadedfiles/hello.txt')
 );

 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://friendsdomain.com/upload.php");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);

 $data = curl_exec($ch);

 if (curl_errno($ch))
{
 print curl_errno($ch);
}
else
{
  curl_close($ch);
 }

 echo $data;

 ?>
```

This is the receiving side code:

```
<?php
$uploads_dir = './phpbackend/';
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) 
{
  echo  "File ".  $_FILES['userfile']['name']  ." uploaded successfully to
 $uploads_dir/$dest.\n";
 $dest=  $_FILES['userfile'] ['name'];
 move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], "$uploads_dir/$dest");
} 
 else 
  {
    echo "Possible file upload attack: ";
    echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
    print_r($_FILES);
  }
?>
```

Please I need some assistance.

Comment: You seem to be using `file` to send, but `userfile` to receive.

Comment: @MikeW aren't those the variable names in different programs and do they really have an effect on one another? since one is to receive and another is for sending from a different server. how does it effects it?

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting up your `cURL` request you're setting up the `POST` variables with this:

```
  $post =array(
    'file' => '@' . realpath('./uploadedfiles/hello.txt')
    );
```

The array keys are the variable names sent in the `$_POST` data.

When you come to unpack the file on the receiving server you're looking for

```
is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']
```

where `'userfile'` should be the variable name used in the POST request sent by the sending machine.

The variables created in the POST data must match the variable names used by the receiving machine or the two machines won't be able to identify the different fields correctly.

At present you're creating the POST data with your file in `file`, but your receiving machine is looking for the file in the `userfile` variable. Your test fails because the variable names don't match, hence the message.